# Lock file could not be created TYPO3

Tags: mod-rewrite, configuration, typo3

I have this error.

**Lock file could not be created**

So far I've done everything that was recommended: I removed all the files from typo3temp, I have given write permissions recursively, still does not work. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is TYPO3 version?

Comment: AFAIR, last time in ver. 6.x I had such problem because of lack of `typo3temp/locks` folder, I created it manually, helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typo3 back-end show this error probably because log file gonna be more than `30 MB`.

To solve this error do change in `localconfiguration.php`

**for the typo3 version < 6**

add this line : `$ TYPO3_CONF_VARS ['SYS'] ['enableDeprecationLog'] = '0 ';`

**for typo3 version > 6**

add this `'enableDeprecationLog' => '0',`

in `'SYS' => array of localconfiguration.php`

I hope this helps u !!!!

Comment: Does this actually answer the question? It seems unrelated to me.

Comment: @reinierpost: Can you post your question ?

Comment: Not my question, the question asked above.

Comment: It's helps to my friend.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had no typo3temp folder, so i created one 

    `/users/pub00/web/html # mkdir typo3temp
    /users/pub00/web/html # chown vmamp:nobody typo3temp/
    /users/pub00/web/html # chmod 775 typo3temp/`